# 404 error when accessing laravel routes under domain and subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have dockerized Laravel app, which runs on nginx. I have api routes in my project like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'V0', 'domain' => '{subdomain}.' . config()->get('app.url'), 'middleware' => ['servicewebauth']], function () {

   Route::get('test-route/{param}', 'AppController@testRoute);

    Route::get('test', function() {
        return 'This is a test';
    });
});

And this is my nginx configuration file:

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /app/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

When I run docker container in local environment everything works fine, but on the production I am getting 404 error for routes under domain 'domain' => '{subdomain}.' . config()->get('app.url'). (Also tried to run docker production build in isolation, it's the same.)
But, when I remove domain part from routes, it works. Did anyone have this problem and what could be the reason?

Comment: How is your app.url configured? Also why not use config('app.url')?

Comment: Ok, I will change it. My app.url is getting value from this .env variable: APP_URL=project.localhost, which points to nginx of  docker container in local environment. (This setup is only for development, I am not in charge for production, but in other two apps I have only changed some urls and works fine on prod.) Do I have to specify a full url of domain in this variable for production? (I have noticed that this is done in other 2 applications)